# KRDC & Rdesktop sessions freezing

Tags: linux, rdesktop

I am using KRDC under kubuntu to access Windows terminal server 2003 on the same LAN.  My session keeps freezing between 5-20 minutes... it seems random how long this is and it's only been happening after the last day or so.  There were some recent updates to Linux (not to the windows terminal server).

This does not happen with windows users.

Does anyone else have this issue and an idea of the cause?

EDIT: I thought I'd try rdesktop just in case it's a KRDC issue.  But it seems that also rdesktop exhibits the same problem.  I decided to have a linux ping running of the server running in the linux shell in the background.  When the freezeup occurred I noticed that also the continuous ping stopped working too.

Comment: I believe somebody uses your account =P

Comment: No, I'm the only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question. It could be related to DHCP in linux.  I've just changed over to using a static IP and haven't had it happen at all since.

Comment: Don't use father's account!

Comment: Yes I'm answering my own question

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue, but have no solution.

However I have a suspicion: try running `ping rdp-host-name` and check the log when a freeze occurs: just to make sure there are no network problems on the way of RDP stream :)
In my case there's a correlation between ICMP packets loss & RDP freezes.

Note that KRDC's RDP implementation differs from the Microsoft's: in MS RDP client there can be a non-documented mechanism for frozen streams reanimation. We'll never know for sure...

P.S. KDE Rocks :)